# Android custom launcher import home screen from available launcher in device like **EVIE**

Tags: android, launcher, android-launcher

I add google launcher-2 code in my application , which is working fine and i also modify the launcher as per requirement. But now i want that when user use my launcher user can import all his homes screen shortcuts and folders to my launcher. Like **Evie** (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=is.shortcut) launcher does. When user open **Evie** launcher first time it gives option to import shortcuts and folders from currently installed launcher applications. And some how it reads the database of other launcher application and mirror the launcher home screen.

I am able to get the list of launcher by using this code :-

```
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    Intent iii = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    iii.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    List<ResolveInfo> lst = pm.queryIntentActivities(iii, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : lst) {
        Log.e(TAG, "New Launcher Found: " + resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
    }
```

Comment: That should not be possible, except for home screens that offer an API for this.

Answer (score 0):

Launcher3 has class named ImportDataTask:

```
/**
* Utility class to import data from
another Launcher which is
based on Launcher3 schema.*/
public ImportDataTask {...}
```

Check it out!